# Find the limit of the following function $h(x)=\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\mathrm{cos}(m!\pi x))^n$.

Tags: analysis

Find the limit of the following function $h(x)=\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\mathrm{cos}(m!\pi x))^n$. Here is my guess. Could anyone check whether it is right, please? Thank you!

It seems right to consider two different cases. First is when $x$ is rational. So long as $m$ is large enough, the cosine term will be either 1 or -1, which leads to oscillation. This, in turn, implies that $h(x)$ has no limit at rational numbers. Second is when $x$ is irrational. Then it is not possible for the cosine term to take 1 or -1. Therefore, we should be able to obtain 0 as the limit.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function#Dirichlet_function and is reasonably famous, I imagine you can find the answers you are looking for now that you know the name.

Comment: You got it right. Notice that for $m$ large the $m!$ not only cancels denominator, but also gives you an even multiple of $\pi$. So, the cosine doesn't give you the $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Look at $h(x)$ like a sequence $\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}{a_m}$. Where 
$$a_m=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\cos(m!\pi x))^n$$

If $x$ is rational, then $x=\frac{a}{b}$ with $b>0$. Then if $m>b$ then $m!x$ is an even number (Why?) hence $a_m =1$ thus $h(x)=1$.

If $x$ is irrational, then $m!x$ is never an integer. Thus $|\cos(m!\pi x)|<1$. Thus means $a_m=0$ for all $m$. Hence $h(x)=0$.

In summary,

$$h(x)= 
\begin{cases}
1, x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
0, x \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$